# Xcode Interface Builder autoresizing views on orientation change

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, autoresizingmask

My view controller content consists of 3 views. I use interface builder on Xcode4. 
Something like that on portrait mode:
[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/a43f88e8f2dd52b2ca41c10d3cdc76e3.png?1342602312))</sub>

I need to autoresize this content on orientation change to landscape: view 2 have constant width, 1 and 3 views must increase width for landscape mode to have close borders to view 2.

Is it possible to implement this behavior via interface builder autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use one more helper `UIView` (let say **N4**). Put views 2 and 3 inside view **N4**.
Align **view 1** with  **view 4** with `autoresize mask` as needed, after that do same for **view 2** and **view 3** inside **N4**.